# Azure FTP - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, ftp, azure-web-app-service, filezilla

when i tring to read the files from azure app services (ftp://myftpurl.net/site/wwwroot/logs).
I am getting below error, When access the last file created in the directory.
"**Response:    550 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.** "

Rest of the files i can able to download.

any help would be appreaciated

Comment: Please tell us your specific usage scenario? I think [this official link](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Dealing-with-locked-files-during-deployment) could useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

> The error message "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" typically indicates that the file you are trying to access is currently in use or locked by another process, preventing you from accessing or modifying it.

The last file created in the directory is currently being used or locked by another process, which is causing the error when you try to access it.

```
- myIP and hostname are the same. In that case, you are trying to write the same file over itself.
```

And if the issue still persists check the below steps

1. Check the file is locked or not

`CSharp Code` to check the file is locked or not.

```
 try
    {
        stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        return true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null)
            stream.Close();
    }
    return false; // file is not locked
```

2. If the file is being used by another process, wait a few minutes and access it.
3. Sometimes the process that's holding the file open will release it after a short period of time.
4. Check if there are any running applications or services that may be using the file you are trying to access. If you find any, try stopping or closing them and then try accessing the file again.
5. If there are any open connections to the file, you may not be able to access it. Make sure all applications that have the file open are closed or disconnected, and then try accessing the file again.

Check your `FTP client` configuration, make sure your `FTP client` is configured correctly and using the appropriate settings for accessing the files on Azure. Also check the permissions to access the files.